# How do I use the Crystal Focus?

Tags: tales-of-maj-eyal

I've found the unique item Crystal Focus, which has the ability "can be combined with a weapon". However, whenever I try this, it seems I don't have a suitable weapon.

What kind of weapon am I looking for? Is this ability restricted to a particular character class, like the alchemist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this thread](http://forums.te4.org/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=24848):

> The crystal focus only works on plain no-ego weapons.

Further, from [this thread](http://forums.te4.org/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=24581):

> Ah yes... the Crystal Focus. When melded with a normal, plain weapon,
>   the results are great. More damage, random magic damage, pushed crits,
>   pushed APR, pushed spellpower. An all-terrain bonus-fest.
>
> Sadly bugged to hell.
>
> Occasionally (had it go both ways) on the Imbue screen it will not
>   activate, and the natural reaction of the erstwhile Player is to click
>   multiple times apon the weapon out of sheer indignant righteousness.
>   This has the unique effect of actually imbuing the crystal focus each
>   click making a game-breaking kill everything weapon with a typical
>   damage range in the hundreds of thousands. Read the new sig of Darkgod
>   for the record damage of this bug. (I think its' around two Billion
>   damage - the RNG flags the sucker with an exponential value!)
>
> Awesome, right? It also makes your Rod of Recall dissappear, rendering
>   this bug a potential game-breaker.

Comment: Ah, only works on plain weapons. That explains a lot. That thread is very interesting. Looks like the bug can be avoided by dropping the Rod, and only clicking once. Looking forward to trying this out now. Thank you!